# Implement a SCons source code formater. Modify a source file before compiling it

Tags: format, scons, clang-format

I want to format my C/C++ source code before every compilation.
I found no information how to do it in SCons.
Ideas I tried:

- What I would need: a Builder that has the same files for source and target. Impossible in SCons because cyclic dependency. env.FormatCode(target='bla.c', source='bla.c')
- Use env.AddPreAction(source, format_action) on the objects resulted in compilation. Partially works, but not incremental with variant dirs.

```
def StyleFormatCCode(env, source):
    sys.path.append('somePath/clangStyleChecker'))
    import styleChecker
    def format_action(target, source, env):
        for file in source:
            styleChecker.main(['-f', '-i', str(file)])

    return env.AddPreAction(source, format_action)

sources1 = env.Glob('*.cpp')
sources = env.Object(sources1)
env.StyleFormatCCode(sources)
```

The style formatter problem is the same as Modify a source file before compilation.
Any idea how to do it or locations where I can find something like this in SCons?

Comment: In addition to the comments in @bdbaddog's answer, this feels like not the right place to format.  It's already relatively common to have editors that can be configured to format-on-save, and it's certainly possible to set up as a commit hook in git.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't do this in process.
If you do it in process you will NOT be able to parallel build any where near as efficiently.
Python has the GIL and so there's very limited multithreading if all the logic is in python.

Secondly, modifying the source file before each compile will cause a recompile the next time around. Since you'll be modifying the sources.

If you're okay with either or both of the above, then something similar to your method would work for you.. ;)

You can reach into the Object and SharedObject builders and add prepend an action to their list of actions. You will be reaching in the innards of SCons to proceed carefully.

Another option would be just to do this logic in plain python (no Builder()s involved) in your SConscript/SConstruct.   That would prevent the rebuilds as the sources are scanned and checked for changes after all the SConscripts have been processed.